# How to conditionally use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` based on values in a certain column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, apply

I have a pandas DataFrame whereby I'm using `pandas.DataFrame.apply()`.

```
dict1 = {'file': ['filename2', 'filename2', 'filename3', 'filename4', 
         'filename4', 'filename3'], 'amount': [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1], 
         'front': [21889611, 36357723, 196312, 11, 42, 1992], 
         'back':[21973805, 36403870, 277500, 19, 120, 3210], 
         'type':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df1)

        file  amount     front      back type
0  filename2       3  21889611  21973805    A
1  filename2       4  36357723  36403870    A
2  filename3       5    196312    277500    A
3  filename4       1        11        19    B
4  filename4       2        42       120    B
5  filename3       1      1992      3210    C
```

My task is to take `N` random draws between columns `front` and `back`, whereby `N` is equal to the value in column `amount`:

```
def my_func(x):
    return np.random.choice(np.arange(x.front, x.back+1), x.amount).tolist()
```

I would only like to apply this function on rows whereby `type` is equal to `A`.

If I didn't have the conditional, I would use `pd.DataFrame.apply()` as follows:

```
df1["new_column"] = df1.apply(my_func, axis=1)
```

To apply this only if `type==A`, I could do something like

```
if set(['A']).issubset(df1['type']):
    df1["new_column"] = df1.apply(my_func, axis=1)
```

However, this doesn't actually work---`my_func` is applied to all functions.

(1) Why doesn't the above work as expected?

(2) How would one efficiently only apply `my_func` to the rows which satisfy `type==A`? In the example above, this would be for the first three rows, and the next three rows would be `NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter your dataframe first then apply `my_func`. Let's use `query`:

```
df1['new_column'] = df1.query('type == "A"').apply(my_func, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   amount      back       file     front type  \
0       3  21973805  filename2  21889611    A   
1       4  36403870  filename2  36357723    A   
2       5    277500  filename3    196312    A   
3       1        19  filename4        11    B   
4       2       120  filename4        42    B   
5       1      3210  filename3      1992    C   

                                 new_column  
0            [21921030, 21908574, 21971743]  
1  [36391053, 36371413, 36394390, 36376405]  
2  [198648, 263355, 197017, 261666, 260815]  
3                                       NaN  
4                                       NaN  
5                                       NaN
```

Comment: What worries me about this approach is that I may apply other functions conditionally. For example, let's say I had another function `func2()` which I would like to apply only on columns of value `type==B`? I think the above would rewrite the elements in `new_column` above, turning them to `NA`. I could of course create a new dataframe, but it seems like there should be an approach which doesn't require that.

Comment: `df1.loc[df1['type']=="A",'new_column'] = df1.query('type == "A"').apply(my_func, axis=1)`

Comment: I don't quite understand the above. This is the code one would use if you were to create further conditional applies (e.g. on B with another function, on C with yet another function, etc.?)

Comment: You could simply copy the statement and modify A to B and change the function.  Then only the A's get updated with the function for A.  And Type b with a function for B.  If you create a more creative test case, I'll attempt a more roboust bit of code.